# UILabel attributedText and minimumScaleFactor

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, uilabel

Is it possible to use minimumScaleFactor and attributed text string at a same time?

```
        [myLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(6, 0, 200, 25)];
    NSMutableAttributedString *attStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"A very long string and its first 20 characters should be bold"];
    [attStr addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17] range:NSMakeRange(0, 20)];
    myLabel.attributedText = attStr;
    [myLabel setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
    [myLabel setAdjustsLetterSpacingToFitWidth:YES];
    [myLabel setMinimumScaleFactor:0.3];
```

This doesn't seem to work. If I set myLabel.text it scales as expected. How I get scaling to work correctly?

Comment: Have you tried sizeToFit after implementing this code...

Comment: No it does not. SizeToFit expands the size of the label's frame large enough to string fit in.

Comment: Did you ever overcome this? I am getting the same error for some reason

Comment: No, I did not. This is quite a tricky problem. Definitely this should work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take the fist 20 character part and get its width, then you can take the rest part's width using same way:

```
CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(500.0,20.0);//write a really long width

//this will turn the expected length of the labels.. 
 CGSize expectedFirstLabelSize = [[[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"A very long string and its first 20 characters should be bold"] substringToIndex:21]
 sizeWithFont:[UIFont  boldSystemFontOfSize:17] constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize lineBreakMode:nil];


 CGSize expectedLastLabelSize = [[[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"A very long string and its first 20 characters should be bold"] substringFromIndex:20] 
sizeWithFont:[UIFont  normalSystemFontOfSize:15] constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize lineBreakMode:nil];
```

then you will know their length's rate.. 
for ex. first part is 140 px, rest is 260 px and your label area is 100 px,
then u can create 2 different labels with 35 px and 65 px.
And then you can use setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth for both of the labels.